# Unit Testing. Before or After creating interface?

Tags: testing, tdd

In my recent project, my team members and I gathered up, went through the requirements, and created interfaces(with method declarations, but not implementations) together that we all agreed on. Then, we started writing unit tests and then implementation.

Now, my project lead is saying that our approach was wrong. He is saying that we should have created a test first, and then come up with interfaces.

One of the reason we came up with the interfaces first was because we thought that we have to have an interface declaration in order to create mock tests.

Which one is the correct approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test Driven Development starts with a unit test.

In your unit tests you define the tree phases: Arrange, Act and Assert. At this moment your code won't compile because the classes/interfaces are not defined yet.

But this steps does help you to think about your interfaces. In your situation, instead of discussing the interfaces and the methods you need with your colleagues on a whiteboard (or something), you could have written a set of unit tests that sketched out the classes and interfaces you needed.

By writing unit tests in a test-first manner, you force yourself to look at the outside of your classes before thinking about the implementation. That's the way to do TDD.

Thinking about mocks when defining all the interfaces for your project is to soon. In your unit test, you test a single class. A concrete object. While writing that object you will come across situations where your class needs other objects. That's the moment you start thinking about dependencies which leads to using interfaces and dependency injection.

Comment: Thank you, you have clarified some of the things I did not understand fully.

Comment: so, we do it like: `private readonly UserRepository _sut;` instead of `private readonly IUserRepository _sut;` (test the CONCRETE object, and not its interface, right?)

Answer (score 2):

**More than TDD**

Start above TDD, and think in terms of stories or use cases, and the requirements they have.  Define the requirements in terms of a test.  Say you're working on a web site selling socks.  The story might read:  as a customer, I need to type in the quantity of items I'm buying so I can get package discounts.  So you create a test that says "customer entered 24 pairs of socks, ensure a discount of 5% was added to the order."  But that's really high level.  You look at the code and say "hey, I don't even support quantity yet."  So you think about line items on your order, and how they need to have quantity.  You write a test for your LineItem object that says

```
LineItemTest::testAddQuantity()
{
    LineItem lineItem = new LineItem();
    Item item = new Item();
    lineItem.add(item);
    lineItem.addQuantity(7);
    ASSERT(lineItem.getQuantity() == 7);
}
```

and you implement the code.  You think harder about quantity at this time, and add a few more tests for things like negative quantities, quantities exceeding a maximum, etc.  Then you figure out the line item's price is something impacted by quantity.  You already have a Price on your item, but not a price extended by quantity.  So you add one because you need one.

```
LineItemTest::testExtendPrice()
{
    LineItem lineItem = new LineItem();
    Currency price = 1.00;
    Item item = new Item(price);
    lineItem.add(item);
    lineItem.addQuantity(7);
    ASSERT(lineItem.getExtendedPrice() == 7.00);
}
```

So we've changed the interface on LineItem by defining a new requirement.

The most important lesson is that if we hadn't thought of ExtendedPrice when designing our LineItem interface, we'd have gotten stuck right here because our requirements desperately call for one.  With TDD, you didn't have to design it in advance, because no matter what you thought during design, you were going to end up needing it when you got here anyway.

**Emergent Design**

This methodology is called Emergent Design, and it's why TDD is often referred to as a design methodology, not a test methodology.  You don't spend a big pile of time in advance, thinking of all the design elements, and what are all the interfaces and exactly what do they do, and what if we need a quantity discount, and what if this and what if that.  That's the kind of Big Design Up Front methodology that leads to errors of omission.  Another example might be that you forget to check for sales taxes on discounts if they use a coupon, or whatever.  Instead, you defer those decisions to only when you need to make them - when you're working on the requirement.

Emergent Design is a different path to achieving results.  It makes you think as you go, instead of thinking in advance, and it lets you react to exactly the facts you have in hand, instead of trying to imagine them all up front.  It takes advantage of software being really flexible and changeable at this stage.

At this time, you also allow all the "what ifs" to enter in.  What if we enter a negative quantity?  Add another test!

**Time saved**

In an Agile world, this approach has another big advantage: if your customer decides to delay a feature in favor of a more important feature, you wasted no time designing it.  It's common for the customer to prioritize things differently.  I hear this kind of decision a lot: "the discounts are not important today, I won't run those promotions till next year.  Right now, I really need you to get the sales tax integration in place."

Unit Testing enables this flexibility.  With unit tests, you can change anything and rerun the tests for free, confident that your change broke nothing else.

**Problems avoided**

A Big Design Up Front doesn't protect you.  On the contrary, it can inhibit you from doing the right thing at the right time.  I've seen teams get stuck with a big design that completely forgot some detail, and instead of fixing the design to add the detail, they patch around the deficiency.  "My project is behind schedule, we can't change the design now, we'll just do a workaround."  That's where true spaghetti code comes from, and it's most often the fault of the process driving bad decisions.

**External dependencies**

Often, despite what you're creating internally, you're still dealing with the outside world.  Services, fixed requirements, legacy database schema, all these are real world problems you have to deal with in TDD.  So if you have an external interface to another system, how do you approach it?  As you would any other requirement: with a test.

This is primarily where your mocks will come into play. You'd create a mock service that does shipping, implementing the existing Shipping interface.  You'd use TDD to write your code to interact with that interface.  You may find it advantageous to write a thin wrapper around it, then access the adapter in your code - that lets you write a mock wrapper instead of writing a whole mock service.

Comment: Thanks, I finally got a time to read the whole thing :). Was a great help.

Comment: Agreed. "Big Design Up Front" does lead to errors of omission. But perhaps more of a concern is that it also leads to errors of redundant inclusion. Elements get designed in because you think you'll need them for some or other feature, but it turns out you don't. These elements waste time, typically end up only partially implemented and poorly tested.

Answer (score 0):

When applying TDD you start from tests first...you want first to write down you test cases which describe the business logic. Along these tests the necessary interfaces/methods become apparent..I think it is not such important either writing first interfaces or tests cases. More important is writing after both these steps the implementations of the interfaces!